# Read values of radiobutton list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have list of radiobuttons with same id. i'm trying to read the value of each radio button but my code always read the value of first radiobutton only.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#rdodoc").click(function () {
            var val = $("[id=rdodoc]").val()
            alert(val);
        });


    });
</script>


@foreach (ReadWord.Models.Document item in ViewBag.lstdocs)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("rdodoc", item.Name)
    <label>@item.Name</label>


}
```

Comment: `.val()` only returns value of the first selected element, you should iterate through the collection, use `.each()` method. Also IDs are supposed to be unique, using attribute selectors doesn't solve the issue, you are selecting the elements in an inefficient  way and your markup is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `id` use `class="rdodoc"`, it is the proper way of doing it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rdodoc").click(function () {
        var val = $(this).val()
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

with the above code, when you click on a radio button it's value will be alerted

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid html to have many elements with the same id. Also, your selector will bind the click event to only one element. Use a class instead as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".rdodoc").click(function () {
            var values = $('.rdodoc').map(function(e) { return $(this).val(); });
            $.each(values, function(e, v) { alert(v); });
        });
    });
</script>

@foreach (ReadWord.Models.Document item in ViewBag.lstdocs)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("rdodoc", item.Name, new { @class = "rdodoc" })
    <label>@item.Name</label>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs of elements are supposed to be unique. Duplicate IDs will render your html document invalid and accessing these elements by ID will only return the first found element. If you want to group the radio buttons then use the name attribute to do so. And to get the values you can then iterate using their unique IDs.

Comment: This code will help you get the values in an array :  var list = $(".elements").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a loop in your javascript as well.
Right now you just GET only 1 value, that's why you see the first one.
and change the id to name or class.

```
$( ".rdodc" ).each(function( index ) {
  alert( index + ": " + $( this ).val() );
});
```

this will alert each of the radio button value.